# How to connect an arbitrary python file to an arbitrary kivy file?

Tags: python, class, module, kivy, communication

So here's the overall code one can run on his computer

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class SnakeGame(FloatLayout):
    pass

class SnakeGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SnakeGame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SnakeGameApp().run()
```

snakegame.kv

```
#: include snake.kv

<SnakeGame>:
    Snake:
        pos: 300, 300
```

snake.py

```
# Control object for the Snake view object in snake.kv

class Snake(Widget):
    def move(self):
        print("Moving")
```

snake.kv

```
#: import Widget kivy.uix.widget.Widget
<Snake@Widget>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 15, 15
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    on_touch_down: self.move() # There is an error here: Snake object has
                               # no attribute move.
                               # How can i connect to the snake.py
                               # file here the same it was automatically
                               # connecting the SnakeGame class in the main.py
                               # file with the SnakeGame class in the snakegame.py file
                               # ???
```

There is an error in the snake.kv file: Snake object has no attribute move.
How can i connect to the snake.py file here the same it was automatically connecting the SnakeGame class in the main.py file with the SnakeGame class in the snakegame.py file ???

Thanks a lot.

I've already made extensive googling but couldn't find anything that helps.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem 2 - touch events dispatched to all widgets

The `on_touch_down` event gets fired even outside of the snake object.

## Solution 2 - on_touch_down callback

1. In *snake.kv*, add `args[1]` to `self.move()` i.e. `self.move(args[1])`
2. In *snake.py*, check for collision, `if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):`.

[Touch event basic](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def move(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

### snake.py

```
class Snake(Widget):

    def move(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("Moving")
            return True     # consumed touch and don't propagate touch event
        return super(Snake, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

## Solution 1 - AttributeError

1. In *snake.kv*, replace [Dynamic Class](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes), `<Snake@Widget>:` with [class rule](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#rule-context), `<Snake>:` because inheritance of Widget is already defined in *snake.py*
2. In *snake.kv*, remove `import` statement, `#:import Widget kivy.uix.widget.Widget`
3. In *main.py*, add `import` statement, `from snake import Snake` **OR** in *snake.kv*, add `import` statement, `#:import Snake snake.Snake`

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from snake import Snake


class SnakeGame(FloatLayout):
    pass


class SnakeGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SnakeGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SnakeGameApp().run()
```

### snake.kv

```
<Snake>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 15, 15
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    on_touch_down: self.move()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: I just figured out a similar solution. But there's still a problem: the on_touch_down event gets fired even in the outside of the snake object. Try to click outside of it and see. How to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: @mctrjalloh: Please refer to the solution in my updated post for your second problem, on_touch_down.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think just found the answer

You'd have simply to do an import in the snake.kv file like this:

```
#: import Snake snake.Snake
```